# Missing right parenthesis error (ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis)

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error

I am trying to create a table and I am getting the error "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis".

```
CREATE TABLE data_create (
studentid NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
name      VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
program   CHAR(4)
CONSTRAINT check_program
CHECK (program = 'CP', 'CPA', 'CSTC', 'CSTY'),
dob       DATE,
email     VARCHAR(20)
CONSTRAINT check_email UNIQUE (email),
phone     NUMBER(10),
feepaid   NUMBER(6)
CONSTRAINT check_feepaid
CHECK (feepaid BETWEEN 0 and 9999.99)
)
```

I have tried several different things but can't get the error to go away. I am brand new to oracle and am not super familiar with the syntax. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: `'CPA` is missing a `'`

Comment: `(program = 'CP', 'CPA', 'CSTC', 'CSTY'),` is just as wrong as `CHECK (program = 'CP' || 'CPA || 'CSTC' || 'CSTY'),` - why don't you use the correct syntax supplied by Gordon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is this expression supposed to be?

```
CHECK (program = 'CP' || 'CPA || 'CSTC' || 'CSTY'),
```

In Oracle, `||` is string concatenation.  Perhaps you mean:

```
CHECK (program IN ('CP', 'CPA', 'CSTC', 'CSTY'),
```

There may be other errors, but this one stood out.

EDIT:

The following works on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3936c):

```
CREATE TABLE data_create (
    studentid NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
    name      VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
    program   CHAR(4)
    CONSTRAINT check_program CHECK (program IN ('CP', 'CPA', 'CSTC', 'CSTY')),
    dob       DATE,
    email     VARCHAR2(20) UNIQUE,
    phone     NUMBER(10),
    feepaid   NUMBER(6)
    CONSTRAINT check_feepaid
        CHECK (feepaid BETWEEN 0 and 9999.99)
)
```

Note I changed the strings to `varchar2()`, which Oracle recommends.  I also suggest you change the `phone` to a string, so it can handle leading zeros.

Comment: Also notice that this solution has a closing single quote for `CPA`

Comment: Changed it and added in the missing ', still getting the error

Comment: @Andrew `'CSTY'),` -> `'CSTY')),`